# Helper Uncaught Error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, helper

I'm getting this error

```
Object.verify_trigger_proccess()@https://[COMPANY].lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/[ID]/components/c/event_layout.js:79:24
Object.eval()@https://[COMPANY].lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/[ID]/components/c/event_layout.js:34:48
```

and this is my lightning component helper

```
refresh : function(component,event,helper){
        window.setTimeout(
            $A.getCallback(function() {
                window.location.reload(true);  
            }), 5000
        );
    },
```

in the Salesforce error, I get `Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]`  the `setParams` is defined here:

```
if (AcId){

                action.setParams({
                    "acID":AcId
                });
```

and it does happen when `AcId` is empty.

I'm also using `setParam` in these two points:

```
showToast : function(title,type,msg) {
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "title": title,
            "type": type,
            "message": msg,
            'duration':'5000',
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
    },
```

And here:

```
delete_trigger_proccess : function(component,event,helper){
        var action  = component.get('c.delAlertevent');
        var alertId  = component.get('v.Alert_id');
        var ownerid  = component.get('v.OwnerId');
        console.log('alertId>>>>>>>>>>'+alertId);
        action.setParams({
            "id_toast":alertId,
            'ownerid' : ownerid
        });
```

How would I catch the error?

Comment: We'll need to see more code than this. The error is saying that `action` is undefined, which probably means there's something wrong at an earlier point in your code.

Comment: I did update the code.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already said

> [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined] and it does happen
>   when AcId is empty.

Instead of `(AcId != '')` use [*any value check*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) `(AcId)`  to check there's any value. That means

```
if (value) {
}
```

will evaluate to `true` if value is **not**:

- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`
- empty string `""`, `''`, ``
- `0`, `0n`
- `false`

Comment: I did update the code to be `if (AcId) { }` but I still get the same error

Comment: please check the var values before every single setParams() function invoking to define which var is null or undefined.

Comment: it does happen now even if the AcId exists

Comment: before ever setParams() I have this code `var action  = component.get()`

Comment: I also tried `isNotBlank()` to no avail

Comment: just check var values before they invoke setParams() func using debugger or console.log(). Check whether server side auraenabled method signature is relevant to your js  action.